# Submit button gets stuck on "sending..."

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a contact form on my website. After filling out the form and clicking submit, the button gets stuck on "sending..." BUT I still receive the email. I think it might have something to do with the ajax portion of my code? Any help is apprecitated.

JS:

```
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data) 
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });

        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });


                    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json' 
            });        

      });   
});
```

Comment: Did you check your console for any errors or something?

Comment: You need to declare your variables in Javascript.  `label` and `$btn` are never declared.  I'm sure this would result in error messages in your developer console.

Comment: I declared my variables but it is still stuck on "sending..."

Comment: Is your callback function executed? I don't think your callback function knows what `$form` is.

Comment: You might find this informative: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to update the button in the `success` block

```
if(data.result == 'success')
{
    // get the button
    ...

    // reset the text.
    $btn.text('Original Text');
```